# How to use dense_rank() to achieve real ranking

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, dense-rank

```
select 
    DENSE_RANK() over (order by score desc) as Rank , 
    username , 
    score 
from users
```

I tried above query and result was as below :

```
Rank    Username    score
-----   --------    -----
1       A           3500
1       B           3500
2       C           3000
2       D           3000
2       E           3000
3       F           2000
```

whereas my required result is :

```
Rank    Username    score
-----   --------    -----
1       A           3500
1       B           3500
3       C           3000
3       D           3000
3       E           3000
6       F           2000
```

how should i edit my query to get my required result?

Comment: Use `RANK` instead of `DENSE_RANK`.

Comment: thank you so much. it solved my problem

Comment: @Behnam You can post the same as anwer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Rank()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms176102.aspx) instead of [`Dense_Rank()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173825.aspx) will solve your problem.

```
SELECT 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Score DESC) AS [Rank], 
    Username, 
    Score 
FROM Users
```

---

Working execution with the given sample data:

```
DECLARE @Users TABLE (Username VARCHAR (2), Score INT)

INSERT INTO @Users (Username, Score)
VALUES
('A', 3500),
('B', 3500),
('C', 3000),
('D', 3000),
('E', 3000),
('F', 2000)

SELECT 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Score DESC) AS [Rank], 
    Username, 
    Score 
FROM @Users
```

So the output will be:

```
Rank UserName   Score
---- --------  ------
1       A       3500
1       B       3500
3       C       3000
3       D       3000
3       E       3000
6       F       2000
```